# Attached property is not updating the value it is bind to (MVVM)

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, mvvm

I have a ScrollViewer filled with green rectangles and I need to report its scroll value (or percentage) on a TextBlock everytime it changes. I also need to be able to change the scroll value by changing the property it is bind to.

I have created an Attached property `ScrollViewerBehavior` which gives me the value I need, and I bind it to a property of my viewmodel (`ScrollValue`) however the value is not updated as the setter is never reached. The viewmodel is correctly linked with the view.

Here is my code:

**View**

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="6*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="0" Background="Gray" local:ScrollViewerBehavior.ScrollState="{Binding ScrollValue, Mode=TwoWay}" >
        <StackPanel>
            <Rectangle Width="50" Height="50" Fill="Green" Margin="5" />
            <Rectangle Width="50" Height="50" Fill="Green" Margin="5" />
            <Rectangle Width="50" Height="50" Fill="Green" Margin="5" />
            <Rectangle Width="50" Height="50" Fill="Green" Margin="5" />
            <Rectangle Width="50" Height="50" Fill="Green" Margin="5" />
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>

    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding ScrollValue}" />
</Grid>
```

**ViewModel**

```
public class MainViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private double _scrollValue = 0;
    public double ScrollValue
    {
        get { return _scrollValue; }
        set
        {
            // This code is never reached 
            _scrollValue = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ScrollValue");
        }
    }
}
```

**ScrollViewerBehavior**

```
    public static double GetScrollState(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (double)obj.GetValue(ScrollStateProperty);
    }

    public static void SetScrollState(DependencyObject obj, double value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(ScrollStateProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ScrollStateProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("ScrollState", typeof(double), typeof(ScrollViewerBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(0.5, (o, e) =>
        {
            var scrollViewer = o as ScrollViewer;
            
            if (scrollViewer == null)
            {
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                double newVO = (double)e.NewValue * scrollViewer.ScrollableHeight;
                scrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(newVO);
                SetScrollState(o, newVO);
            }
        }));
```

I can't see what I missed

Comment: without really diving into it: you do have your DataContext set somewhere?

Comment: Yes, it is set directly in the constructor of the view

Comment: As a note, `if (scrollViewer == null) { return; } else { ... }` looks odd. It should be `if (scrollViewer != null) { ... }`. Besides that, it makes no sense to call SetScrollState in the PropertyChanged handler of the ScrollState property. You should be setting the property when the ScrollViewer is scrolling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not see anywhere in the code where you are changing the value of `ScrollValue`. Since your attached property is bound to this, it only updates when `ScrollValue` in your view model is updated. Unless I am misunderstanding your explanation, you want to update `ScrollValue` everytime the scroll bar value changes. To do that you can hook into the `ScrollChanged` event:

(I only updated your code just show what was needed)

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ScrollStateProperty =
    DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("ScrollState", typeof(double), typeof(ScrollViewerBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(0.5, (o, e) =>
        {
            if (o is ScrollViewer scrollViewer)
            {
                scrollViewer.ScrollChanged += OnScrollChanged;
            }
        }));

    private static void OnScrollChanged(object sender, ScrollChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is ScrollViewer scrollViewer)
        {
            SetScrollState(scrollViewer, scrollViewer.VerticalOffset);
        }
    }
```